# Bottom of page is being cut off when there is more than 2 rows of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a movie review app. Once you get past the 3rd row on PC and I believe the 3rd or 4th movie listing on mobile, it cuts off the review as seen in the image below. Only the buttons are cut off in that image, but if I added another row, it would be 100% cut off/hidden.

I tried adding `height: 100%` `width:100%` to my html and body elements, but that adds a second vertical scrollbar when I show the movie listings?

How can i fix this?

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2a0c07254d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css"></link>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="./public/favicon.ico">
    <title>Reviewer</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="notification"> 
  </div>

  <header>
    <h1>Reviewer</h1>
    <h5>Create a movie review below or search for movie reviews by the movie title!</h5>
  </header>

  <div id="error-div"></div>

  <form autocomplete="on" class="create-movie-form" action="submit">
    <label for="title">Movie Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" alt="Movie title" id="title" placeholder="Movie Title" />
    <label for="runtime">Movie Runtime (in minutes, numbers only):</label>
    <input type="text" name="runtime" alt="Movie Runtime" id="runtime" placeholder="Runtime" />
    <label for="rating">Movie Rating (Between 1 and 10, numbers only):</label>
    <input type="text" name="rating" alt="Movie Rating" id="rating" placeholder="What's your rating for this movie?" />
    <label for="review">Movie Review:</label>
    <textarea name="review" alt="Movie Review" id="review" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Movie review"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="create-btn">Create movie review</button>
  </form>

  <form autocomplete="on" id="get-movies-form" action="submit">
    <label class='search-by-title-label' for="search-for-movie-input">Search by movie title:</label>
    <div class="get-movies-div">
      <input type='search' name="search-for-movie-input" alt="Search input" id='movie-title-to-search-input' placeholder="Search" />
      <button id="get-movie-by-name-btn">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <button id='display-all-movies-btn'>Display All Listings</button>

  <div id='movie-list'></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/functions.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/movies.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
html, body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* KEYFRAMES */

@keyframes notificationSlideDown {
    0%, 100% { transform: translateY(-50px);}
    10%, 90% { transform: translateY(0px);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes notificationSlideDown {
  0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);}
  10%, 90% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes notificationSlideDown {
  0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);}
  10%, 90% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px);}
}

@keyframes sectionSlideDown {
  0% { transform: translateY(-15%);}
  100%{ transform: translateY(0);}
}

@keyframes h1-SlideDown {
  0% { transform: translateY(-20%);}
  100%{ transform: translateY(0);}
}

@keyframes h5-SlideDown {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  0% { transform: translateY(-100%)}
  100%{ transform: translateY(0);}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}


/* Notification box */

#notification {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 119, 255);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  -mox-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#close {
  margin: auto;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 102;
}

.notification-animation {
   animation: notificationSlideDown 1.5s ease forwards;
}


/* Header Elements */

header {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: rgb(0, 119, 255); 
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1, h5 {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  animation: h1-SlideDown 1.2s ease;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 3%;
  animation: h5-SlideDown 1.3s ease;
}

/* DIVS */

.get-movies-div {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.delete-and-update-btn-div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#error-div, #section-error-div {
  color: rgb(243, 86, 86);
  text-align: center;
}

#section-error-div {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}


/* FORMS */

.create-movie-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-top: 3%;
}

#get-movies-form {
  margin-top: -5%;
}



/* LABELS */

label {
  color: rgb(0, 119, 255);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.search-by-title-label {
  margin-left: 15%;
}


/* INPUTS */

input, textarea {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px rgb(173, 173, 173) solid;
  margin: 0 auto auto auto;
  padding: 2.5% 1.5%;
  width: 70%;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
  transition: .2s;
  border-color: rgb(0, 119, 255);
  outline: transparent;
}

#movie-title-to-search-input {
  width: 44%;
}



/* BUTTONS */

button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2.2%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 119, 255), rgb(0, 97, 243)); 
  border: solid 1px transparent;
  margin: 5% auto auto auto;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  transition: .2s;
  transform: scale(.97);
  background-color: rgb(0, 119, 255);
  outline: rgb(0, 119, 255);
}

#create-btn {
  width: 70%;
}

#get-movie-by-name-btn, #display-all-movies-btn {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#get-movie-by-name-btn {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -14%;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2.1% 1%;
}

#display-all-movies-btn {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
}

.delete-btn, .update-btn {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 1.5%;
  width: 30%;
}

.delete-btn {
  margin-right: 2%;
}


/* MOVIE LIST */

#movie-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  column-gap: 1fr;
  row-gap: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

section {
  border: 1px rgb(223, 223, 223) solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px #d6d6d6;
  outline: transparent;
  background: #fff;
  color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  position: relative;
  animation: 
    sectionSlideDown .5s ease-out,
    fadeIn .5s ease-in;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2% 0 5% -10%;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(0, 119, 255);
}

ul {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.rating,
.runtime,
.title,
.review {
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

.id {
  display: none;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0 15%;
  }

  #error-div {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
  }

   label {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 25%;
   }

   .search-by-title-label {
     margin-left: 25%;
   }

   input, textarea {
     width: 50%;
     padding: 1.5%;
   }

   #movie-title-to-search-input {
     width: 34%;
     margin-right: 0;
   }

   #create-btn, #display-all-movies-btn {
     width: 50%;
     padding: 1.2%;
   }

   #get-movie-by-name-btn {
     width: 15%;
     padding: 1.3%;
     margin: 0 25% 0 1%;
   }
   
   #movie-list {
    grid-gap: 2.5%;
   }
   
  section {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  h5 {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0 25%;
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 1% 0 -3% 0;
    font-size: 50px;
  }

  label {
    margin-left: 32.5%;
   }

   .search-by-title-label {
     margin-left: 32.5%;
   }

   input, textarea {
     width: 35%;
     padding: 1%;
   }

   #movie-title-to-search-input {
     width: 26%;
     margin-right: 0;
   }

   #create-btn, #display-all-movies-btn {
     width: 35%;
     padding: .9%;
     margin-top: 1.5%;
   }

   #get-movie-by-name-btn {
     width: 9%;
     padding: .85%;
     height: 10%;
     margin: 0 32.4% 0 .25%;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  #error-div {
    top: 70px;
  }
}
```

This is the HTML generated by my JavaScript for each movie review/section.

```
// Generate HTML for section elements holding movie data.
function generateHTML(res) {
  const movie = res.data;

  for (let i = 0; i<movie.length; i++) {
    const sections = document.createElement('section');
    sections.innerHTML = `
    <div class='id'>${movie[i].id}</div>
    <div id="section-error-div"></div>
    <ul>
     <li> Title: <p class='title'>${movie[i].title}</p> </li>
     <li> Runtime: <p class='runtime'>${movie[i].runtime}</p> minutes</li>
     <li> Rating: <p class='rating'>${movie[i].rating}</p>/10 </li>
     <li> Review: <p class='review'>${movie[i].review}</p> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="delete-and-update-btn-div">
      <button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
      <button class="update-btn">Update</button>
    </div>
    `
  movieListDiv.appendChild(sections);
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: If `height` doesn't work, probably `min-height` could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe removing

```
overflow: hidden;
```

from

```
#movie-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  column-gap: 1fr;
  row-gap: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;    <--- remove that
}
```

will fix that issue.

Comment: Yup! That seems to do the trick! I don't even remember adding that haha. Thanks for the help!!